# GTA V running smooth on win 10

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, windows-10

Playing Grand Theft Auto V on Windows 8, I was hitting 30/40 fps, on medium graphic quality with no limits.

I upgraded to Windows 10, and now I am constantly hitting 60 fps, on high graphic quality.

With ignore limits, Grand Theft Auto V is using more then 2Gb, but still no lag or drop in frame rate.

Does Windows 10 allow the dedicated GPU to share RAM?

Specs:

- 1GB Shapphire Radeon HD 7770 GHZ Edition
- Intel Core i5 3330 3.0-3.2 GHz
- 8GB Corsair Vengance DDR3 1600 MHz

Comment: How do you know how much *dedicated video memory* does GTA V consume?

Comment: In settings graphic it say an estimated max value that would be consumed. I don't know exactly at the moment how much it consumes.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, The OS can optimize how programs behave in general, but modern GPUs don't share system RAM. The exact point to having onboard VRAM is that is is more accessible (via a faster bus) for the GPU, than system memory.

Comment: Also, if you were never hitting 60 fps on Win8 (not even standing still and looking into a corner), that means the problem is not in data loading (having less than necessary RAM or VRAM means the game has to periodically load stuff there from disk or RAM respectively).